# Swift NSDate Xcode error - SourceKitService terminated

Tags: xcode, nsdate, xcode6, swift-playground

```
import Foundation


var currentTime = NSDate()
println("It is currently", currentTime)
```

This Swift code is very simple and should work, correct? Why am i receiving an error that says "SourceKitService terminated - editor functionality currently limited"
 Am I doing something wrong or is it the beta's fault?

Comment: It should be like: `println("It is currently \(currentTime)")`

Comment: Or...(I think that first one might be wrong), `println("It is currently" + currentTime.description)`

Comment: Regardless of whether you're doing something wrong, SourceKitService shouldn't be crashing. You can file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com to bring it to the Swift team's attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use string interpolation as Jack Wu suggested in the first comment:

```
println("It is currently \(currentTime)")
```

The `println` primary function does not take multiple arguments. You could also use

```
println(currentTime)
```

However, the fact that your first (syntax error) attempt causes Xcode 6 to crash (at least it does for me) is certainly a bug. You should just get an issue reported.

Comment: Thanx! Switching to string interpolation worked. I'm actually a new developer and I only know basic objective-c. Now I'm switching to swift so stuff are still confused.